# Print folder permissions in octal

Tags: ssh, permissions

I have an ubuntu server on rackspace cloud with nginx..The following prints all the file sizes for folders. I want to show all permissions on the same directory.

```
$ du -sh */
788K    foo/
500K    bar/
931K    baz/


$ du -sh */
wrwx    foo/
0777    bar/
```

When I try viewing some folders, it says perm denied. I am using normal SSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a command like `ls -ld * | grep "^d"`

To see permissions in octal you can use `stat -c "%a %n" */`

Note that `chmod` can use symbolic permissions `chmod go+rx mydirname`

Comment: I get drwxrws--x etc.. How can I see the CHMOD codes instead of that format.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: See updated answer.

Comment: Argh, stat on OS X doesn't have %a for their -f (format) flag - any ideas on OS X?